# How to use n-tier application development

Tags: electron, atom-editor

I am a .net desktop app developer. I use c# and WPF. I used SQL Server as my database.

Now I want to learn electron, node.js and would like to code in HTML, CSS and Javascript. Also, as everything mentioned above is open-source/free I would change my database as well. Now I will be using MySQL.

In .net we were using n-tier application development. I know that n-tier application development is not specific to .net, so I think it's possible with electron, node.js, HTML, CSS, Javascript using Atom as development tool.

In .net my projects were structured as:

```
MySolution
   |--Entities
   |    |--Student.cs
   |    |--Teacher.cs
   |--Repositories
   |    |--RepositoryBase.cs
   |    |--StudentRepository.cs
   |    |--TeacherRepository.cs
   |--WPFApp
   |    |--Window.xaml
   |    |--App.xaml
   |    |--App.config
```

The above mentioned structure is just a small demo. In reality we used WCF services and much more. We always have had near about 20 projects for a single Desktop application.

I would like to do same in electron, node.js, HTML, CSS, Javascript and if possible jQuery. Can anyone please guide me about how do they use n-tier applicaiton development in above mentioned app?? If possible can anybody please post a small working demo??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've known about it for 10 years, I'd imagine, but had never heard of it as being referred to as "n-tier" and had to look it up.  The most common multi-tiered pattern in the Node.js world, is "MVC".  I am guessing you're used to that pattern, yourself, or the MVVM pattern that I've seen mentioned in .NET circles.

Anyway, I only wanted to make that distinction in hopes of improving your search results; you will probably find better hits with searches for "MVC" than for "n-tier" in places like npmjs.org.

There are several MVC frameworks available and they should be drop-in ready for Electron development.  Backbone is rather popular, and the first that comes to mind, but there are also many, many, others.

Analogous to the multi-project structures you're probably used to in .NET, you will find that Node.js development is, also, typically subdivided into multiple "modules".  Assuming you want to offer your project as open-source, you will build it as multiple NPM modules and push each to NPM.. then you will use `npm install xxxxx` in your main project to bring them all in.

If you are not planning to publish your modules as open source, you can also look into npmjs.org's private module service or, like us, host your own using a solution such as "Sinopia".

Migrating to Node.js can be a bit overwhelming and there will be a lot of information to swallow.  If I could offer two tips that have been invaluable in my own journey, I would say:

1. Conform to Node.js and its community, do not try to coerce it to conform to you.
2. Always try to avoid writing code.  Just about anything, generic, that you can think to write has already been written and is available on NPMjs.org.  Utility libs, frameworks, etc.  It sucks having to learn someone else's code, but it pays dividends, especially in cases where the open-source editions are well support and/or have a large-ish community.

Also, to go one step further on #1 .. you will probably find that NoSQL (especially MongoDB) is often preferred over MySQL in the Node.js circles.  Its another mind bender for those of us who grew up on SQL, but you should, at least, carefully consider it.

Best of luck,